# How to sign XML using private key contained in smartcard for a web application?

Tags: x509certificate, private-key, xml-signature, signedxml

I was looking for a solution to sign XML using unexportable private key (this require passphrase/secret password to be informed by user input for create the hash using it) contained in usb token (smartcard etc) for a web application. I have made a c# class library to make this but obviously the code is executed in server-side, so I can't access the usbtoken/smartcard of the client over internet, unless it's plugged in the server pc (so my solution may be installed in local network of my customers and the usbtoken plugged in server's usb. It's working like that today but I want to change this for the customer use its token in his machine)

I have created a code using SignedXml, X509Certificates and other classes, to achieve this, but I was looking for equivalents in silverlight class library for encapsulate all this things and execute it in client side, but unfortunately SignedXml can't be used in Silverlight (not exists..).

I have created an ActiveX for doing this successfully but my solution now only works in Internet Explorer/Windows, and it's not very easy to maintain because of my business logics.

Anyone can help me with this please? Any suggestions are very welcome.

If I can port my activex solution to silverlight, or if its possible to do that using other MS Technology that can be executed in other browser/OS.

Sorry for bad English, not a native speaker. Thank you.

Comment: For Modern Browsers, use Browser Extension to do the signing from the device connected to client. Please refer to parts of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Answer (score 1):

Java applet is a better option than the ActiveX.

Silverlight won't give you access to certificate storages, and its development has stopped (Silverlight 5 is officially the last version).

Our company offers a ready to use solution for distributed cryptography which includes ActiveX, Java applet and Flash module for client-side activities. This solution is discussed in details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656100/signing-pdfs-on-a-server-document-using-a-signature-from-the-user/10656679#10656679).