# How to implement digital signature in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, digital-signature

I have a asp.net web application.

I want; users can digitally sign PDF documents with certificates installed in the client machine. Users have a PIN. They must upload file and enter their unique PIN. If certificate is installed and true  signed the document and stored at server.

I dont know any plugin for this. I m not sure about my explanation and i hope you have some ideas about that.

Comment: **iTextSharp** Library, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14488/E-signing-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp

Comment: Thank u @GopeshSharma i'll search more and try it. If it success i'll share.

Comment: Current **iTextSharp** http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Comment: @cocln grt, please do share...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signing PDFs on a server document using a signature from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656100/signing-pdfs-on-a-server-document-using-a-signature-from-the-user)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228106/x-509-digital-signatures-encryption-workflow-library-recommendations and my answers there.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclosure: I work for CoSign]

Yes, we have customers doing what you ask for, with the process mediated by the developers web app (written in ASP.net or other languages). See our [CoSign Signature Web Agent](http://www.arx.com/digital-signatures/cswa) sdk.