# Adding Digital Signature to pdf from USB device in java

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature

Actually i don't have much knowledge in java Security.
My requirement is Add Digital Signature to pdf from USB device
in a client machine,If any one you worked on this type of issue
Please assist me the link,

Thanks,

Comment: iText is a PDF framework for Java that allows you to add signatures to PDF documents. Take a look at that: http://www.itextpdf.com/ .

Comment: You may want to take a look at iText, as @Henrik said, especially [this document](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) by the main iText architect demonstrates its current features concerning digital signatures. Of special interest might be the section on "Signing a document using a USB token"

Answer (score 2):

I've written a white paper about digital signing and PDF. It also explains what such an USB token is about. You can download this document for free from this URL: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean having Java code on the server and needing to sign the document on the client side? Such task requires having client-side mechanisms (usually a Java applet or ActiveX control or some standalone application) which will do the actual signing job.

Our SecureBlackbox library has a distributed cryptography add-on which lets you accomplish the task easily. You will find detailed description of the add-on [on our site](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-dc.php) or in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656679/47961).

If you need to sign the data in client-side Java code (i.e. the USB device is local to the code), then you can use PDFBlackbox package of our SecureBlackbox product - it supports operations with USB tokens and cryptocards.

Comment: Interesting - but I have never heared of a "non-exporable private key" ;)

Comment: @Robert - now you do. Cryptographic hardware doesn't let you extract the private key or symmetric key - this is one of main benefits of using this hardware.

Comment: Don't take comments with smileys too serious. This was just a broad hint because of the typo in your diagram.