# How to construct a certificate based on another

Tags: c#, asp.net, digital-signature, digital-certificate, x509certificate2

I need to send a certificate through an asp.net page.
An ActiveX would read the certificate from user's PC and with a click of a button, somehow the certificate should go to server to sign a document (private key)
I was thinking of filling hidden asp input fields and reconstruct the certificate at the server.
Is this approach viable or it's a better approach? Should I try to do the same thing using silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

No way. The private key in most cases is not exportable (i.e. the activex can't read the certificate's private key) and in all cases you may not transfer the private key anywhere. The proper approach is to send the hash of the signed data to the client and sign it there (on the client side).

We have Distributed Cryptography add-on in our SecureBlackbox product that does exactly what I described above. See the detailed description in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656679/47961) on SO.