# PKCS#11 access from the browser

Tags: browser, pkcs#11

I am trying to write a web client that communicates with a web service to electronically sign documents. The web client must also communicate with a PKCS#11 card for cryptographic operations (sign the digest, ...).

Is there any up-to-date project/technology that allows me to communicate with the smart card from any browser ?
Note: the reader is of type: Gemalto IDBridge CT30

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For now Java applets remain the only more or less widespread technology. As browsers started to block Java, it is possible to run Java applets as standalone processes using Java Web Start. In our Distributed Cryptography add-on for SecureBlackbox, [described in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656679/47961), we are currently doing exactly this - launch the applet via WebStart. BTW I welcome you to check our solution, as it already does what you are trying to implement.